# To change a git user in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I have two github accounts and now I don't know how to switch on the previous one.

[image]

It seems like I'm switched to the GreeenGoo account but when I do commits I anyway see the VladSparkco user.

[image]

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project directory (Or use Android Studio terminal) to check the global settings using:

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email
```

After that check the local configuration for the project to see if matches the GitHub account you want to use:

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

If it's not matching, you need to update this using these commands on the project directory.

```
git config user.name "Your name"
git config user.email "Email from the account you wanna use"
```